# Adding child node values

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the firebase Database of a child node of a particular user under the "users" node:

```
"L1Bczun2d5UTZC8g2LXchLJVXsh1" : {
  "email" : "orabbz@yahoo.com",
  "fullname" : "orabueze yea",
  "teamname" : "orabbz team",
  "total" : 0,
  "userName" : "orabbz@yahoo.com",
  "week1" : 0,
  "week10" : 0,
  "week11" : 0,
  "week12" : 0,
  "week2" : 0,
  "week3" : 17,
  "week4" : 0,
  "week5" : 20,
  "week6" : 0,
  "week7" : 0,
  "week8" : 0,
  "week9" : 10
},
```

IS there a way to add up all the values of `Weeks 1` down to `week 12` and have the total sum in the `total` key?

I am curently thinking of bringing all the values of week 1 - week 12 brought into the angular js scope then adding up the values and then posting the total back in the firebase databse key `total`. But this sounds too long winded. is there a shorter solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Firebase DB doesn't have any DB functions as you'd have in SQL. So the options you have is to get the data and calculate it in Angular as you say. Or update a counter when the weeks are added to the user (when writing to the DB). Then just read the counter later